# sudo mount -o remount,rw /

Tags: bq

I have a question on running this command (`sudo mount -o remount,rw /`) at start up so I don't have to do it manually. I'm trying to do this on Ubuntu Aquarius M10 phablet.

Comment: Have you tried the answer suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683357/ubuntu-run-command-on-start-up-with-sudo)?

Comment: Look into `/etc/fstab`. You might be able to get the same result by adding/editing a line there.

Comment: I guess my question was on why I have to run this command every time I start my pad?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! The factory settings for device like BQ Ubuntu touch pad doesn't allow to run manual updates. All is required is to enable the device. You can do that with the following command (enable/disable): **$ android-gadget-service enable writable** Just remember that you cannot update your apps with device being enabled. Turn it off for auto update.